# My forge mod loader can't find a "mod" called ivtoolkit and wont let me play. I didn't even get a mod called ivtoolkit

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

forge won't let me play mods on 1.7.10. Whenever I open the game on forge 1.7.10, it brings up a screen that says:

> forge mod loader has found a problem with your minecraft installation the mods and versions listed below cannot be found: ivtoolkit  minimum version 1.0.1

I don't have any file anywhere on my computer called ivtoolkit and I never have. It recommends a file that would explain, but the file doesn't exist either. The screen cannot be gotten out of without shutting down or pushing the windows button on my keyboard and there's no way to get to Minecraft on it.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: You don't have any other mods installed?

Comment: i de-installed all of my mods, and that didnt do anything

Comment: thanks for your concern anyways, i just made a backup of minecraft, after searching my computer for one. im sure ive backed minecraft up before, but i couldnt find one

Comment: also thanks for the edit, this is my first time using this website, and im still working my way around how it works

Comment: i get the feeling that this "ivtoolkit" mod may have been installed and altered something outside what you have "de-installed" but i don't know the mod or how it was programmed so i can't say for sure (strange Forge is able to id it rather than just crash). after backing it up try deleting your .minecraft folder so the launcher can redownload a fresh copy of 1.7.10 and reinstall forge.

Comment: 2014-11-30 11:56:48 [INFO] [Minecraft-Client] Stopping!

Comment: i found that in the forge log in my new backup

Comment: i also never had any ivtoolkit mod, and something similar that i had, i had many months ago and no problems

Comment: i also have many re-installments of forge, many different downloads of forge, all of them are doing this, but i might try installing it again

Comment: maybe a mod may have used it as a child mod which installed which altered other stuff outside what you have uninstalled which is why i suggested getting a fresh clean copy of .minecraft and re installing just Forge

Comment: also 1.8 forge crashes even if i dont have any mods installled

Comment: i think by [minecraft client] stopping! it means that minecraft with forge 1.7.10 decided to stop working

Comment: ill try deleting the .minecraft... if i can find it. it seems to have dissapeared

Comment: it wont let me delete .minecraft because it says i have a file called.minecraft open...

Comment: probably because it's still running in the background. if your on Windows open up Task Manager (ctrl + alt + delete), locate processes and close off any java ones (as there should be no OS critical tasks that need Java running)

Comment: thank you very much (sincerely) it seems to have fixed the problem

Comment: Ok. going by [SevenSidedDie's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/207716/30879) it seems the mod named in the error is a library mod used by a previous mod you had which wasn't fully removed. wiping out the .minecraft folder removed all trances of it. if you did one of the mods in the link listed then i suggest up voting the answer. otherwise as a guess it may have been someone who liked the library mod and used it them-selves

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because tech support for modded Minecraft is off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

#### You need to install Ivorius' IvToolkit

You've installed one of [Ivorius' mods](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1276287-ivorius-mods-structures-dungeons-drugs-statues) without following the instructions. Go back and follow them.

#### Or don't use Ivorius' mods

If you don't want to install the IvToolkit library mod that Ivorius' mods require, then you could also just remove the Ivorius mod that requires IvToolkit.